# What clients does cloudamqp think are "up-to-date" what does this mean and why?

Tags: rabbitmq, cloudamqp

On the rabbitmq diagnositic page of cloudamqp (a hosted rabbitmq service), I'm getting warnings about rabbitmq clients being out of date. However, no information seems to provided about what clients rabbitmq thinks are out of date, what clients are not out of date and why this matters?

Why is cloudamqp giving this warning? And what clients are "new enough"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's checking if there is a later version of the client, for example if you are using the NodeJS client https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node, and you are connecting a client with version 0.7.1, and the latest version is v0.8.0, it will give you a warning.

We give this warning since clients are regularly updated with bug fixes, to make sure your RabbitMQ cluster can run as smooth as possible.

Comment: Cool thanks for the reply. So "new enough" is "as recent as is possible".